# Firebase authentication in flutter works locally but not after deployment to playstore

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using `verifyPhoneNumber` method of Firebase authentication and waiting for the `codeSent` callback to get the verification id. When I receive verification id, I move to the next view to input OTP from user. This works locally, but after deploying to playstore, the `codeSent` event is not triggered.

This is what is making it difficult to debug:

- I get the SMS with OTP when I trigger `verifyPhoneNumber`, which means fingerprint is correctly configured (assumption)
- It does not move to the next view, so the `codeSent` event is not triggered (assumption).

How can I debug it? Has anyone faced similar problem? Here is the code I'm using:

```
Future verifyPhoneNumber(String phone) async {
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        verificationCompleted: _onVerComp,
        verificationFailed: _onVerFail,
        codeSent: _onCodeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _onCARTimeout);
  }

  void _onVerComp(PhoneAuthCredential pac) async {
    UserCredential credential = await auth.signInWithCredential(pac);
    verifyUser(credential.user?.phoneNumber?.toString());
  }

  void _onVerFail(FirebaseAuthException e) {
    showErrorMessage(message: e.message);
  }

  void _onCodeSent(String verficationId, int? verId) {
    navigateTo(OtpView(verId: verficationId));
  }

  void _onCARTimeout(String code) {
    showErrorMessage(message: "timeout: " + code);
  }
```

Comment: Did you sign the apk on firebase with your SHA-1 hash?

Comment: yes I did. If I give wrong SHA key, then it throws a different error and I don't get the SMS. But here I'm getting the SMS with OTP.